# How to correctly Scan pq arrays?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

In a PostgreSQL database I have a table:

```
| ORGANIZATION_ID | FACTOR_IDS   | CALCULATION_VALUES  |
|-----------------|--------------|---------------------|
| 1               | {1,2,3,4,5}  | {0,66.66,50,100,80} |
| 2               | NULL         | NULL                |
| 1               | {6,7,8,9,10} | {0,77.77,60,110,90} |
```

In Go I make a query to that table and then try to use the `Scan` method. Unfortunately I get an error:

```
Trace: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

My code:

```
type Entry struct {
    OrganizationID int
    FactorIDS pq.Int64Array
    CalculationValues pq.Float64Array
}

rows, err = database.DBGORM.Raw(`SELECT * FROM ANALYTICS`, ID).Rows()

if err != nil {
    utils.Logger().Println(err)
    return
}

defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var entry *Entry

    if err = rows.Scan(&entry.OrganizationID, &entry.FactorIDS, &entry.CalculationValues); err != nil {
        utils.Logger().Println(err) // <- RAISE ERROR
        return
    }

    if entry.FactorIDS != nil {
        for index, value := range factorID {
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Also if I change the type from `pq.Int64Array` to `*pq.Int64Array` the Go compiler gives the error: `Cannot range over data *pq.Int64Array` for the code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nil pointer dereference is on `entry`.  Fix by changing `entry` from a pointer to a value:

```
for rows.Next() {
    var entry Entry  // <--- change on this line
    ... remaining code as in question
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I decided to use such statement: `entry := &Entry{}`.

Answer (score -1):

It was panicking because of the these &entry.OrganizationID, &entry.FactorIDS, &entry.CalculationValues. As entry is of pointer type and you haven't initialize the memory to it. If you want the  struct of pointer type you can initialize it like this:

```
for rows.Next() {
    entry:=new(Entry)

    if err = rows.Scan(&entry.OrganizationID, &entry.FactorIDS, &entry.CalculationValues); err != nil {
        utils.Logger().Println(err) // <- RAISE ERROR
        return
    }

    if entry.FactorIDS != nil {
        for index, value := range factorID {
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
```